# Add multiple widgets area in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, sidebar, area

i am trying to add `multiple widgets area`, the code below i have posted is to add multiple widgets. it works, but the name of `second sidebar` repeats two time. is any solution for it ?

```
if ( function_exists ('register_sidebar')){
    register_sidebars (1, array(
    'name'          => 'wpwidget',
    'id'            => 'wpwidget',
    'description'   => 'Sidebar for showing ad and section list on the template career.php',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' 
));
    register_sidebars (2, array(
    'name'          => 'wpwidget2',
    'id'            => 'wpwidget2',
    'description'   => 'Sidebar for showing ad and section list on the template example.php',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>' 
 ));
}
```

Comment: you can mention like for second widget also register_sidebars (1, array());

Answer (score 2):

`register_sidebars` registers multiple sidebars and you've provided `2` as an argument for the second function that's why it is registering two sidebars.
In your case it would be a better idea to use `register_sidebar`.

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars

Answer (score 2):

this code looks like you register three sidebar 1. wpwidget 2. wpwidget2 3. the same wpwidget2

if you trying to add 2 sidebar then write this code

```
if ( function_exists ('register_sidebars')){register_sidebars (2, array( 'name' => 'wpwidget %d', 'id' => 'wpwidget2', 'description' => 'Sidebar for showing ad and section list on the template example.php', 'before_widget' => '', 'after_widget' => '', 'before_title' => '', 'after_title' => '' )); }
```

Comment: register_sidebars(2, array( ..........so on. if i use this, in widget area two widgets register with same name. how to solve it.

Comment: @Sprytechies has pointed out the issue for you. The 2 in this part of your code: `register_sidebars (2, array(` tells Wordpress to create 2 sidebars - however you are only passing one array of details so both sidebars get the same details...

Answer (score 0):

In the following code i am adding code to create custom Multiple Widget or sidebar in the wordpress.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_custom_widget' );

    function my_custom_widget{
    register_sidebar( array(

            'name'          => __( 'Header Widget Area', 'themname' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
            'description'   => __( 'Appears in the Header section of the site.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h1>',
        ) );


register_sidebar( array(

            'name'          => __( 'Header Widget Area', 'themname' ),
            'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
            'description'   => __( 'Appears in the Header section of the site.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
            'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title'   => '</h1>',
        ) );
    }
```

I think that would help me for any other question contact me

Comment: using this, the theme get blank?